# I get this error when I have coffeescript files in my assets/javascript folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, asset-pipeline

I get the following error when I have coffeescript files in my `assets/javascript` folder

```
  ExecJS::RuntimeError in Users/sessions#new
```

If I remove the coffee script files, everything works perfectly.. What is the issue? How can I solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ExecJS](https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs) is a Ruby lib that allows JavaScript to be run. It's needed to compile CoffeeScript because the CoffeeScript compiler is, itself, a JavaScript lib.

But ExecJS doesn't contain a JavaScript runtime itself; instead, it looks for one on your system. It's hard to tell from the error you're describing exactly what's going on, but it seems that whichever JavaScript runtime ExecJS is trying to use is failing.

You might want to try adding [therubyracer](https://github.com/cowboyd/therubyracer) to your project's gems; it's a JS runtime that, in principle, should work on all platforms.